An interesting Hamiltonian path problem concerning the connectivity of subgraphs
Suppose there are $n$ players, $P_1,...,P_n$, requiring any $t<n$ players to be able to talk to each other, each two players can share a telephone line, when there is a logical connection path (Hamilitonian path) between $t$ entities composed of telephone lines, then the $t$ entities can realize the online chat.
Q: At least how many telephone lines are required for each player to satisfy the online chat between any $t$ players, that is, to satisfy the $C(n,t)$ chat arrangement combinations? Furthermore, the connection path is an Hamilitonian path.
The question can be formally considered as a subgraph connection problem, as noted by Ingix.

A simple graph on $n$ nodes is considered, the vertices being the players and the edges being the telephone lines between them. The condition that the graph must fullfill is that the induced subgraph for any set of $t$ nodes must be connected. (The connected graph meets the existance of an Hamilitonian path)

In the case of $n=4,t=3$, each player can hold at least 2 shared phone lines to satisfy online chat between any $t=3$ players.

For $P_1$: Shares a telephone line with $P_2$ and $P_4$ respectively, denoted as: $line_{12},line_{14}$, similarly:

For $P_2$: $line_{21},line_{23}$.

For $P_3$: $line_{32},line_{34}$.

For $P_4$: $line_{41},line_{43}$.


Note that: $line_{ij}=line_{ji}$, there is a total of 8/2=4 telephone lines among $n=4$ players.
For any combination, e.g., $(P_1,P_3,P_4)$, the connection path can be built by the two lines: $line_{14}=line_{41}$ and $line_{34}=line_{43}$.

Therefore, each player at least requires 2 phone lines can satisfy chat between any $t=3$ players.
In addtion, I tried other cases, including $(n=5,t=4),(n=5,t=3),(n=5,t=2)$.

For the case $(n=5,t=4)$, each vertex requires 2 edges to meet the connection for any subgraph containing $t=4$ vertices.
For the case $(n=5,t=2)$, each vertex requires 4 edges to meet the connection for any subgraph containing $t=2$ vertices.
For the case $(n=5,t=3)$, one vertex needs 4 edges and other vertices require 3 edges can satisfy the connection for any subgraph containing $t=3$ vertices, as shown in the below figure.



Imo, this is a poorly-worded question and is difficult to parse.

To me it looks likes a simple graph on $n$ nodes is considered, the vertices being the players and the edges being the telephone lines between them. The condition that the graph must fullfill is that the induced subgraph for any set of $t$ nodes must be connected.
If that interpretation is correct, then the minimality question posed is potentially ill-formed. While some kind of 'symmetrical' solution where each vertex has the same degree is a reasonable assumption, it may not be the case. That means there could be minimal solutions where vertices have not all the same degree.

@Ingix, Your understanding is correct! I have modified my question by your comment.

@AdamRubinson  I have revised my question for clarity.

Note that a Hamiltonian path is a stronger condition than connected, especially for larger $t$. For example for $t=4$, the 3 point star (one 'center' vertex connected to 3 other vertices that don't have any connections between themselves) is connected, but does not have a Hamiltonian path.

I can only provide some generalizations of X.H. Yue's results for small and large $t$.
For $t=2$, the condition is just a reformulation of "every pair of vertices must have an edge between them", so only the complete graphn on $n$ vertices is possible. That means the degree of each vertex is the maximal $n-1$.
For $t=3$, if a vertex has no edges to 2 other vertices, then the subgraph of those 3 vertices is not connected. That means each vertext can have at most one (other) vertex it is not connected to.
So if $n$ is even, you can remove a perfect matching from the complete graph and that is the best you can get, with each vertex having degree $n-2$.
If $n$ is odd, then there is no perfect matching and one vertex will have to 'keep' all its edges from the complete graph. In the example $n=5, t=3$ given in the question, the edge between P$1$ and P$4$ has been removed from the complete graph, as well as the edge between P$3$ and P$5$. P$2$ has kept all its $4$ edges. So in general for odd $n$ the minimal graph has $1$ vertex with degree $n-1$, while the others have degree $n-2$.
If $t=n-1$, the minimal graph can't be a tree (assuming $n > 2$), as removing a 'middle' vertex would destroy connectedness. But with $n$ edges it works, by simply connecting all vertices in a circle (I think this is the only possible solution). By removing one vertex, the remaining $n-1$ vertives form an unbranching path, which is connected and has a Hamiltonian path (itself).

Dear Ingix, I submit another question which is more clear than this question.
